# server license on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: server, windows-10, license

I'll explain my problem: I have a software on ubuntu that uses a license, I created a server license (I had already done it years ago on another computer and it worked). The server appears to be working: License:
27008 @ hostname
lmutil - Copyright (c) 1989-2017 Flexera Software LLC. All rights reserved.
Status of Flexible License Manager on Sat 3/6/2021 12:15 pm

License server status: 27008 @ hostname

in the .log file I read: Info ===
16:21:49 Options file used: None
16:21:49 Vendor daemon is a CVD: No
16:21:49 The FlexNet licensing service is installed and compatible: no
16:21:49 FlexNet License Service Version: -NA-
16:21:49 Access to TS: no
16:21:49 TS access time: -NA-
16:21:49 Number of VD restarts since LS start: 0
16:21:49
16:21:49 === Network information ===
16:21:49 Listening port: 53000
16:21:49 Daemon select timeout (in seconds): 1
16:21:49
16:21:49 === Host Information ===
16:21:49 Host used in license file: hostname
16:21:49 HostID blocked by node in license file: s3d9d2361y5t
16:21:49 License server hostID: s3d9d2361y5t
16:21:49 Running on Hypervisor: not determined - treat as physical
16:21:49 ============================================ == ==
16:21:49 TCP_NODELAY NOT enabled
16:21:49 Listener Thread: Running
16:21:49 Starting the Diagnostic Port Listener (DPLT) thread
16:21:49 Starting the diagnostic output thread (DRQT)
16:21:49 DPLT: running
16:21:49 DRQT: running
16:21:49 DPLT: waiting for logger connection.

But when I try to connect from my PC (windows) it tells me: the remote license server is not available. i checked the firewall on ubuntu and it is active, ports are open too

Comment: I also edited my windows hosts file by adding the line with ip and machine name

Comment: what ss --antpu  on the ubuntu box is saying? Can you telnet from the windows machine to the license server port 53000 ? ( I know windows doesn't ship anymore telnet, but may you can find an alternative to verify network connectivity)

Comment: thanks I solved, the windows internet connection did not allow me to connect to the server, using the hotspot from the mobile phone it worked